# Why isn't my 'Shift' key working in shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 and keyboard shortcuts containing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key aren't working, "not working" meaning <kbd>Shift</kbd> is ignored. They are not working in applications with shortcuts containing <kbd>Shift</kbd> either like the Vivaldi browser. So if I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> I get the action for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. <kbd>Shift</kbd> works normally when typing.

I'm on a Thinkpad T460S which otherwise works perfectly.